# How can I create a MethodInfo from an Action delegate

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, nunit-addins

I am trying to develop an NUnit addin that dynamically adds test methods to a suite from an object that contains a list of `Action` delegates.  The problem is that NUnit appears to be leaning heavily on reflection to get the job done.  Consequently, it looks like there's no simple way to add my `Action`s directly to the suite.

I must, instead, add `MethodInfo` objects.  This would normally work, but the `Action` delegates are anonymous, so I would have to build the types and methods to accomplish this.  I need to find an easier way to do this, without resorting to using `Emit`.  Does anyone know how to easily create MethodInfo instances from Action delegates?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried Action's Method property? I mean something like:

```
MethodInfo GetMI(Action a)
{
    return a.Method;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to "create" a `MethodInfo`, you can just retrieve it from the delegate :

```
Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Hello world !");
MethodInfo method = action.Method
```

Comment: +1, You and Fede both had the correct answer.  I accepted his, because tie goes to the guy with two less digits on his rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
MethodInvoker CvtActionToMI(Action d)
{
   MethodInvoker converted = delegate { d(); };
   return converted;
}
```

Sorry, not what you wanted.

Note that all delegates are multicast, so there isn't guaranteed to be a unique `MethodInfo`.  This will get you all of them:

```
MethodInfo[] CvtActionToMIArray(Action d)
{
   if (d == null) return new MethodInfo[0];
   Delegate[] targets = d.GetInvocationList();
   MethodInfo[] converted = new MethodInfo[targets.Length];
   for( int i = 0; i < targets.Length; ++i ) converted[i] = targets[i].Method;
   return converted;
}
```

You're losing the information about the target objects though (uncurrying the delegate), so I don't expect NUnit to be able to successfully call anything afterwards.

Comment: sorry, I was thinking of MethodInvoker when I saw MethodInfo.

Comment: +1 (to get you back to zero).  As it turns out, d.Method was all I needed.  It does work in NUnit, although the naming is funky.  I'll have to create my own test class to fix that.