# How do I invoke a MethodInfo that was created from an anonymous method?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, anonymous-methods, nunit-addins

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576640/how-can-i-create-a-methodinfo-from-an-action-delegate), I asked how to get a `MethodInfo` from an Action delegate.  This Action delegate was created anonymously (from a Lambda).  The problem I'm having now is that I can't invoke the `MethodInfo`, because it requires an object to which the `MethodInfo` belongs.  In this case, since the delegates are anonymous, there is no owner.  I am getting the following exception:

> > System.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type.

The framework I'm working with (NUnit) requires that I use Reflection to execute, so I have to play within the walls provided.  I really don't want to resort to using `Emit` to create dynamic assemblies/modules/types/methods just to execute a delegate I already have.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code that generates the exception?

Comment: The code's in the NUnit framework, but it fails when NUnit makes a call to the Invoke method on the MethodInfo.

Answer (score 3):

You already got the Method property.  You'll need the Target property to pass as the 1st argument to MethodInfo.Invoke().

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var t = new Test();
        Action a = () => t.SomeMethod();
        var method = a.Method;
        method.Invoke(a.Target, null);
    }
}

class Test {
    public void SomeMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.  I suspect there must be more going on in the innards of NUnit.  I found a workaround, however kludgey it may be.  They made all the methods virtual, so I pass it the MethodInfo, but just override the method where it's called, and call the Action directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that lambda methods, even when declared in a static context, are defined as instance methods.

Solution:

```
public static void MyMethodInvoker( MethodInfo method, object[] parameters )
{
    if ( method.IsStatic )
        method.Invoke( null, parameters );
    else
        method.Invoke( Activator.CreateInstance( method.DeclaringType ), parameters );
}
```